# C++ builder indy intercept IdHTTPProxyServer to insert header

Tags: proxy, c++builder, indy

I want to insert header of external script over https inside browser. For those purpose i use C++ builder with IdHTTPProxyServer component. I read Document from Response event but dont know how to just insert one simple .js. -> cause Document property is read only, on the other side BeforeCommandHandler want append with script (in code under i use just text to insert for simplicity)

**How to insert .js external script in C++ builder?**

Here is what i done so far.

```
    void __fastcall TForm5::IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPResponse
    (TIdHTTPProxyServerContext *AContext)

{
    Memo1->Lines->Append("\nOn Response!!!\n" + AContext->Document);
}


void __fastcall TForm5::IdHTTPProxyServer1BeforeCommandHandler
(TIdCmdTCPServer *ASender, UnicodeString &AData, TIdContext *AContext) {
try {
    Memo1->Lines->Add(AData);
    UnicodeString sa = AData;
    AData = L"<html>Something</html>" + sa;
}
catch (int e) {
    MessageBeep(100);
}
}
```

Comment: Security note: HTTPS proxies allow man-in-the-middle attacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TIdHTTPProxyServer::OnBeforeCommandHandler` event is triggered before a client's request is processed.  The `AData` parameter is the original request.  This event is meant for logging/altering commands before they are parsed.

The `TIdHTTPProxyServer::OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event is triggered after a client's request headers have been received but before a connection is established to the target server and the client's request body is read and sent to the server.

The `TIdHTTPProxyServer::OnHTTPResponse` event is triggered after a server's response headers have been received but before the response body is read and sent to the client.

So none of those events will help you.

Neither will the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext::Document` property, for that matter.  That property does not contain the document data, as you are assuming. It contains the server-relative URL of the document being requested instead.

To do what you are asking for, set the `TIdHTTPProxyServer::DefaultTransferMode` property to `tmFullDocument` and use the `OnHTTPDocument` event.  The `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext::TransferSource` property will tell you if the data is coming from the client or the server.

You will have full access to the headers and body data and you can modify them as needed.  Just make sure you update the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.Headers`, in particular the `Content-Length` header, if you modify the body data.  The body data is provided as a `TStream` object (specifically, a `TMemoryStream`).  So you can either modify the stream's content directly, or you can create a new `TStream` object with your desired content (the `VStream` parameter of the event is passed by reference so you can re-assign it).

For example:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm5::IdHTTPProxyServer1HTTPDocument(TIdHTTPProxyServerContext* AContext, TStream* &VStream)
{
    if (AContext->TransferSource == tsServer)
    {
        String s = ReadStringAsContentType(VStream, AContext->Headers->Values[L"Content-Type"], QuoteHTTP);

        // this is NOT thread-safe! TIdHTTPProxyServer is multi-threaded,
        // you must synchronize with the main thread in order to safely
        // update UI controls...
        //
        // Memo1->Text = s;

        s = L"<html>Something</html>" + s;

        delete VStream;
        VStream = new TStringStream(s, Sysutils::TEncoding::UTF8);

        AContext->Headers->Values[L"Content-Length"] = VStream->Size;
        AContext->Headers->Params[L"Content-Type"][L"charset"] = L"utf-8";
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx Remy will try that